# Content Security Policy (CSP) error while load base64 image in web page

Tags: reactjs, azure, react-tsx, content-security-policy

In my React web app, I need to implement an image cropper feature. To achieve this, I utilize a file input tag to allow users to select an image file. I then display this selected image using a data URL. Everything functions correctly on localhost. However, when I host the app, I encounter a Content Security Policy (CSP) error. Despite experimenting with various meta tags, I haven't been able to resolve this issue.

> Refused to load the image
> 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAqAPf/ANqhzua/3vTi8OK12evJ5K4zlM6Avvfp9OS63Pry+daVyZs1heCt1c1/vcJhrdGJwqI0i9ONxLM+mvjt9u7S6Jksgp0shIgmc9SQxn0kataYycp1uPz2++Ky2NSOxfDW6/Ha7JIqfPPe7t6p0tiazMVpsu7U6bE4lvv1+rlNor5aqcBcq7A3l9+q1OjE4ezN5oElbvbm89CGwbBKmshxtrhKoc+DwPz3+7pRpOjC4OCw1oQlcLxVptqezsp4uZUrfvjq9apEleS4244oecVss9+t1MdttNmdzOnG4u3Q57ZFnrZEntyk0Prw+Oa93sRmsNui0PPf760xk9WSx+fA39CEwPjs9uzM5ua83rhlpfXk8teWyteYyuS22mgdWL1xrHQhYtym0eW73LRAnNKKw+Gu2IwodsdxterH48x6u7xTpbM8md2m0sR8tdefy9uhz7FBmfnw+OvL5fDY671Xp/Tj8...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'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "default-src https: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that
> 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
> fallback.

i need a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

This is could be a default content-security-policy set by framework/webserver/proxy etc. You will need to allow data: sources for images. You can do this by expanding the default-src directive, but this would allow this source also for scripts and styles etc, which may not be desired:
"default-src https: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data:"
Alternatively you can implement the img-src directive, which is likely better:
"default-src https: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https: data:"
Your first task might be to understand where and how the existing policy is being set.

Comment: thank you for the response.
In my staticwebapp.config.json. file there is a code for excludes the images, which is why that error occurred.